# What reasons would text not appear on a page as a heading for radio buttons?

Tags: css, html

I am writing in HTML and my title for a radio buttons section on my page isn't appearing. Also I can't seem to organize the radio buttons vertically, nor am I able to get my spacing right with a section above my radio button section. Here is a link to my Codepen where I am writing my code,

https://codepen.io/DevinCassidy/pen/xeZpxx

```
<div>
 <br>
 <h2 for="radio-buttons"> What type of Deejaying do you prefer?</h2>
</div>
<div>
<input type="radio" id="analog deejaying" name="drone" value="analog deejaying">
<label for="analog deejaying">Analog Deejaying</label>
</div>

<div>
<input type="radio" id="digital deejaying" name="drone" value="digital deejaying">
<label for="digital deejaying">Digital Deejaying</label>
</div>
```

\\\\\\

Comment: Your CodePen example is riddled with `HTML` validation errors—some of which are affecting the rendering of elements on the webpage. Fix those errors and your `h2` will show as expected.

Comment: This worked thanks so much!! I also had some tags that I hadn't closed which ended up fixing the problem, once closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to close select tag, thats occurs errors. Also i recommend you set one unique Id to html tags. Because its can cause to bad consequences.

```
<select id="dropdown" name="" class="dropdown">
          <option disabled value>Select an option</option>
          <option value="Turntables">Turntables</option>
          <option value="CDJ's">CDJ's</option>
          <option value="Controller">Controller</option>
          <option value="Any music playing device">Any music playing device</option>
</select>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jRMzrE