# Is there a way to write your code so that an element doesn't act as a child element to another element?

Tags: html

An element in my code is acting as a child element to another line of code above it and I’m trying to re-write the code, so the element stands on its own. Here is a link to my Codepen:

https://codepen.io/DevinCassidy/pen/pBNNKY

I tried a page break and enclosing another div element around it.

```
\\\
    <div>
    <h2 id="Price">Price</h2>
    <section id="pricing">
    <div id="online">
    <div class="level">Online
    </div>
    <h2>$1,599.00</h2>
    <ol>
    <li>Plus Free Shipping</li>
    </ol>
    <button class="btn">Select</button>
    <br>
    <div id="in-store">
    <div class="level">In-Store
    </div>
    <h2>$1,599.00</h2>
    <ol>
    <li>*Out the door!*</li>
    </ol>
    <button class="btn">Select</button>
    </section>
\\\\\\
```

Comment: Which elements should be siblings instead of parent and child? What are you trying to achive?

Comment: There were some closing `</div>` tags missing in your HTML code. I edited it and gave it a proper indentation. As _you_ should!

Comment: I did a roleback and do the corrections in my answer

Comment: What does "acting as a child element to another line of code" mean?

Answer (score 2):

They do so, because they  ***are*** nested

A cleaned and proper indented code looks like this

```
<div>
  <h2 id="Price">Price</h2>
  <section id="pricing">
    <div id="online">
      <div class="level">Online</div>
      <h2>$1,599.00</h2>
      <ol>
        <li>Plus Free Shipping</li>
      </ol>
      <button class="btn">Select</button>
      <br>
      <div id="in-store">
        <div class="level">In-Store</div>
        <h2>$1,599.00</h2>
        <ol>
          <li>*Out the door!*</li>
        </ol>
        <button class="btn">Select</button>
      </div><!-- this div was missing -->
    </div><!-- this div was missing -->
  </section>
</div><!-- this div was missing -->
```

Through the indentation you will see that in fact, the `<div id="in-store">` is a child of `<div id="online">`. You should do it like this

```
<div>
  <h2 id="Price">Price</h2>
  <section id="pricing">
    <div id="online">
      <div class="level">Online</div>
      <h2>$1,599.00</h2>
      <ol>
        <li>Plus Free Shipping</li>
      </ol>
      <button class="btn">Select</button>
    </div><!-- inserted because <div id="online" should be closed -->
    <!-- <br> not needed, because <div>s are block elements -->
    <div id="in-store">
      <div class="level">In-Store</div>
      <h2>$1,599.00</h2>
      <ol>
        <li>*Out the door!*</li>
      </ol>
      <button class="btn">Select</button>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I forked your codepen and made some corrections: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/7cec5ac558e7c4fdaecbd8ac1d269178

1. Dont close your `<img>` elements; wrong: <del>`<img src=""></img>`</del>, correct: `<img src=""/>` or just `<img src="">`
2. Don't use `<br>` to make room between elements. Use CSS `margin` for this
3. `<br>` tags don't close `<div>` elements. Only `</div>` does
4. Always indent your code. Codepen can do it automatically for you: Either mark all code and then hit <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> or click on the downward facing caret (`v`) on the top right of your HTML code area and choose *Tidy HTML* from the drop down.
5. Codepen shows improper HTML tag-nesting by giving the unexpected closing tags a different background-color. See here for an example: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/3263405edba14d071b84d4860aac9a73

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the [first time OP has been told this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55563956/what-reasons-would-text-not-appear-on-a-page-as-a-heading-for-radio-buttons#comment97827759_55563956)